# Webgl-Earth: rotate earth only horizontally in both directions

Tags: javascript, webgl-earth

I am developing an app, where I am using [webglearth](http://www.webglearth.org/) for drawing earth. now I am able to rotate it only horizontally through javascript while mouse is dragged. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/72g8bny7/59/)

```
earth.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.latitude + ', ' + e.longitude);
    if (e.longitude && e.latitude) {
      earth.on('mousemove', function(e) {
        console.log(e.latitude + ', ' + e.longitude);
        if (e.longitude) {
          //console.log('in',earth.getCenter(0),e.longitude);
          //earth.setView([earth.getCenter()[0],e.longitude]);
          earth.setCenter([earth.getCenter()[0], e.longitude]);
          //earth.setCenter([e.latitude,e.longitude]);
        }
      });
    }
  })
  earth.on('mouseup', function() {
   earth.offAll('mousemove');
  })
```

The problem is that the earth rotates to any two points clockwise or anticlockwise, whichever is closest. I don't find any method in the documentation where I can rotate it clockwise or anticlockwise. Has anyone does that before. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you using webgl-earth v2 ?

Comment: yes http://www.webglearth.com/v2/api.js is cdn